# How to pass a functional component as a prop in Typescript and render it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the code below, how can I:

1. type the icon properly so React.createElement can create it?
2. Render the icon if not using React.createElement()?

```js
function DefaultIcon () {
  return <svg></svg>;
}

interface ExampleProps {
  icon?: React.ReactElement; // JSX.IntrinsicElements also errors
}

function Example({ icon = <DefaultIcon /> }: ExampleProps) {
  const Icon = icon;
  return (
    <div>
      {React.createElement(icon)}
      {/* ^Shows Error #1 */}
      {React.createElement(icon as React.ReactElement<any>)}
      {/* ^Shows Error #1 */}
      <Icon />
      {/* ^Shows Error #2 */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Error #1

```py
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.

Argument of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | FunctionComponent<any> | 
ComponentClass<any, any>'.ts(2769)
```

Error #2

```py
JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Key Insight**: `React.createElement()` only takes references to components (ie., `Icon`), not an instance of it. To clone an instance of a component (ie., `<Icon />`), use `React.cloneElement()`

With that in mind, here are the two methods to recreate a component:

### 1. Pass an *Instance* of the component as props

a) To render: `{icon}` 
b) To recreate: `React.cloneElement(icon)`

- You can also provide the typing in the `React.ReactElement<>` prop definition as seen in `icon2` or cast the type as in `icon3`.

```js
function DefaultIcon() {
  return <svg></svg>;
}

interface ExampleProps {
  icon?: React.ReactElement;
  icon2?: React.ReactElement<SVGSVGElement>;
  icon3?: React.ReactElement;
}
    
function Example({ icon = <DefaultIcon />, icon2, icon3 }: ExampleProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {icon}

      {React.cloneElement(icon, { className: "block" })}

      {React.isValidElement(icon2) && (
        React.cloneElement(icon2, { className: "block" })
      )}

      {React.isValidElement(icon3) && (
        React.cloneElement(icon3 as React.ReactElement<SVGSVGElement>, {
          className: "block"
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

### 2. Pass a *Reference* to the component as props

a) To render: `const Icon = icon` and `return (<Icon />)` 
b) To recreate: `React.createElement()`

- Note the updated prop definition and default passed in

```js
function DefaultIcon () {
  return <svg></svg>;
}

interface ExampleProps {
  icon?: React.FC; // <-- new type definition
}

function Example({ icon = DefaultIcon}: ExampleProps) {
  const Icon = icon;     // ^ new default fallback
  return (
    <div>
      {React.createElement(icon)}
      <Icon />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I also learned something about `React.createElement`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this?

```js
function DefaultIcon() {
  return (
    <svg
      width="24"
      height="24"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path
        d="M4.57574 12.5757C4.34142 12.8101 4.34142 13.1899 4.57574 13.4243C4.81005 13.6586 5.18995 13.6586 5.42426 13.4243L4.57574 12.5757ZM15.6 3C15.6 2.66863 15.3314 2.4 15 2.4L9.6 2.4C9.26863 2.4 9 2.66863 9 3C9 3.33137 9.26863 3.6 9.6 3.6H14.4V8.4C14.4 8.73137 14.6686 9 15 9C15.3314 9 15.6 8.73137 15.6 8.4L15.6 3ZM5.42426 13.4243L15.4243 3.42426L14.5757 2.57574L4.57574 12.5757L5.42426 13.4243Z"
        fill="#404040"
      />
    </svg>
  );
}

interface ExampleProps {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/require-default-props
  icon?: React.ReactNode;
}

function Example({ icon = <DefaultIcon /> }: ExampleProps) {
  return <div>{icon}</div>;
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Oh man, I'm so dumb. Yeah that works. Would you mind also sharing how to make the `React.createElement()` work too if you're familiar with it? Normally `React.createElement(icon as React.ReactElement<any>)` works but somehow still erroring in this case... :S. What does work is... `React.createElement(icon as any)` but... I guess that's a last resort...

Comment: @wongz Sorry, I couldnt make it with `React.createElement()`. let's wait for another one to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you cannot set jsx as a default value for props in typescript instead try to modify this code

const Icon = icon || DefaultIcon by using this expression we are evaluating that if the code icon is undefined DefaultIcon would be used. then remove the default value in props.

Comment: I did that exactly but I'm still getting the error `JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)` for some reason...